# Preferred INNER JOIN linking sequence

Tags: inner-join

I am linking three tables from the FDA's MedWatch system that have a common Individual Safety Report, or ISR, field. The three tables are Demographics (unique record), Drugs (unique record, but linked to the Demographics record) and Reactions (one or more records, each linked to either the Drugs or the Demographics record).

My question is that since the Reactions.ISR can be INNER JOINed to either the Drugs or the Demographics table, is there a preferred way?

E.g. can be:

```
SELECT Demographics.Case, Demographics.ISR, Drugs.DrugName, Reactions.PT
  FROM (Reactions INNER JOIN Drugs ON Reactions.ISR = Drugs.ISR) 
    INNER JOIN Demographics ON Drugs.ISR = Demographics.ISR
```

which links in a Demographics <- Drugs <- Reactions hierarchy

or:

```
SELECT Demographics.Case, Demographics.ISR, Drugs.DrugName, Reactions.PT
  FROM Reactions INNER JOIN (Drugs INNER JOIN Demographics ON Drugs.ISR = Demographics.ISR)
    ON Reactions.ISR = Demographics.ISR
```

which independently links the Drugs record and the Reactions record(s) to the Demographics record.

Both return the same recordset, but I wondered if one method was preferred over the other as a best practice, perhaps making the query execute faster. i.e. is it possible to improve the query performance by altering the JOIN sequence?

Answer (score 0):

To compare the performance of two queries you should look at their execution plans. For instance in this case you might find that you get identical plans in which case that proves that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

How a query is optimized depends on the database.

In terms of inner joins (and where clauses) its often best to start from the most restrictive table (or condition) first and then link out to the "wider" joins/conditions.

Given that these joins aren't that restrictive - i.e. there aren't any further conditions applied then they'll probably be equivalent - look at the query plans of the two approaches to check.